# Apply functions like MEDIAN to individual elements in an array formula - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am using the MEDIAN function to calculate the overlap of two date ranges.
The formula looks something like this

```
=MEDIAN(A18,C18+1,$C$8+1)-MEDIAN(A18,C18+1,$B$8)
```

`A18` & `C18` are date range 1

`B8`  & `C8`  are date range 2

I would like to turn this into an array formula similar to this to sum the results for multiple rows

```
{=SUM(MEDIAN(A18:A24,C18:C24+1,$C$8+1)-MEDIAN(A18:24,C18:24+1,$B$8))}
```

This only works if MEDIAN is applied separately to each element in the arrays `A18:A24` & `C18:C24`.

Currently, Excel concatenates the arrays contained within each MEDIAN call and returns the overall median, leaving only one value for SUM to sum. And that is the 'wrong' result for what I need to do.

Is there a way of forcing excel to apply MEDIAN to each element in my arrays? Ie is there a way to force excel to return an array from the MEDIAN function.

If this is possible it allows me to avoid a 120,000 element array or a macro enabled workbook.

Comment: You can insert another column and add your formula in it
    =MEDIAN(A18,C18+1,$C$8+1)-MEDIAN(A18,C18+1,$B$8)
and then apply the sum over this column

Comment: No, unfortunately you cannot coerce `MEDIAN` into returning an array of values. It should in theory be possible to use `AGGREGATE` with `function_num` and `k` parameters of `16` and `0.5` respectively, though it does not appear to accept the necessary constructions (using either `INDIRECT` or `OFFSET`) to pass multiple ranges as its `array` parameter. I can give you a single-cell array formula solution if you like, though it's necessarily convoluted and potentially resource-heavy. As such, unless you have a strong objection to @usmanhaq's proposed solution, I suggest you take that approach.

Comment: Yeah the objection is that the column approach in my case is what leads to the 120,000 cell array, which pushes the file size up enough to be annoying. B8 and C8 change along another dimension. (the cell references in my sheet are different to here)

Comment: Should have used more meaningful references in hindsight (I just pulled the formula from a different part of the sheet where I also use it). Where C8 and B8 are fixed it absolutely makes sense to use a column.

Comment: So in your actual set-up how large are the ranges being processed? Larger than those given here (rows 18 to 24), I imagine? If they're not too large, it might still be worth considering a single-cell solution without the use of additional, helper columns.

Comment: Size of matrix would be around 200 rows and 600 columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool `MEDIAN` formula. But you can't use `MEDIAN` as you desire with an array formula since `MEDIAN` always returns a *single* result (not an array).

I have a solution to your problem, but it's somewhat sluggish/respetitive:

*(I have included comments to the right of the formula to explain what is happening)*

```
= IF(C18:C24>C8,     // (For each cell in C18:C24) If the value is greater than C8
     C8,             // Then C8 is the upper bound
     C18:C24)        // Else, the specific value from C18:C24 is the upper bound
  -                  // (minus sign)
  IF(A18:A24<B8,     // (For each cell in A18:A24) If the value is less than B8
     B8,             // Then B8 is the lower bound
     A18:A24)        // Else, the specific value from A18:A24 is the lower bound
```

This returns an *array* of the overlaps of date ranges, *except* that it is possible that these results will return negative numbers (if an overlap doesn't occur), but in this case you want to return `0`.

You can get around this with another `IF` statement.

```
= IF(formula < 0, 0, formula)
```

Where `formula` is the first formula I have above.

Side note: Normally in this situation, you'd be able to avoid typing out `formula` twice with something like this:

```
= MAX(formula,0)
```

Except this won't work when the `formula` itself returns an array since `MAX` only returns a single result. This is a similar problem you are experiencing with `MEDIAN` in the first place.

All in all without comments, this is the formula to sum up the values:

```
= SUM(IF((IF(C18:C24>C8,C8,C18:C24)-IF(A18:A24<B8,B8,A18:A24))<0,0,
          IF(C18:C24>C8,C8,C18:C24)-IF(A18:A24<B8,B8,A18:A24)))
```

Of course, this is an array formula, must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Cheers mate. Good to have confirmation that there is no way to make MEDIAN operate as  I need it to here. I knew there would be a solution involving IF's, cheers for putting one together. No doubt it will help others that find themselves here. I might be able to simplify my specific problem a bit to stop the IF formula being too crazy

Comment: Yep, alot of Excel functions like `OR`, `AND`, `MEDIAN`, `MAX`, `MIN` (just to name a few) unfortunately *usually* don't work well with array formulas since they always only return a scalar result. Anyway, if this answer helps you, I would appreciate you marking it as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.

Comment: Hi @mechcaptain. There can be 4 possibilities (1) Date range A is fully before date range B (2) Date range A is fully ahead of date range B (3) Date range A is before date range B but overlapping (4) Date range A is ahead of date range B but overlapping. I think you have catered for only two of these

Comment: @usmanhaq I accounted for all four possibilities. The `IF` statements separately determine the upper and lower bounds.